# Bringing QGIS Menu bar back after hiding it

Tags: qgis, gui

I was trying to save customization templates in QGIS 2.4 and have managed to hide the MENU bar. Now I cannot access `Settings->Customization` to switch it on again.

I even un-installed and deleted the `.qgis2/` folder from my user but it always loads without the menu bar now.

How do I get the MENU bar back?

Answer (score 4):

If you are using **GNU/Linux**, you can go to `/home/USER/.config/QGIS/QGISCUSTOMIZATION2.conf` and set:

```
Menus\mSettingsMenu=true
```

If you are on **Windows** (I've tested on Windows XP), you can press `Windows+R` and execute the command `regedt32.exe`. This opens the Windows Registry.

Now go to:

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER
  Software
    QGIS
      QGIS2
        QGISCUSTOMIZATION2
          Customization
            Menus
```

And set `mSettingsMenu` to `true`.

---

This should make your menu bar visible again. Now, from the `Settings -> Customization` you can enable the rest of QGIS menus.