# Status bar in Qgis

Tags: qgis-2.14

the status bar on my version of qgis 2.14, is not displaying. I have tried activating it via the plugins but to no avail. How can I get the status bar displaying the coordinate
?

Comment: Can you see how your `Customization` is set at the moment? (Go to `Settings | Customization`). By clicking on the `Enable customization` check box, you can find a **StatusBar** tree. If it is unchecked, turn it on and restart QGIS.

Comment: Thank you so much. I have just tried this and even upgraded to 2.18, but still having the status bar not displaying. I still need help on this.

Comment: Searching this site yielded this Q&A [I hid the QGIS Menu bar, how can I bring it back?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/133707/i-hid-the-qgis-menu-bar-how-can-i-bring-it-back). It seems first step you can try is to restart QGIS with **--nocustomization** option (see the first part of answer by Matthias Kuhn). If this does not work, then see Germán Carrillo's answer.